# Animation while navigating among UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I want to create some animation while navigating from one UserControl to another UserControl. It can be any simple animation like we have effects in MS PowerPoint.

How can I start?

**Edit:**

Lets take following xaml

```
<StackPanel>
                    <Label>
                        <Hyperlink Click="ConfigureAccounts_Click">
                            <TextBlock>Configure Accounts</TextBlock>
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </Label>
                    <Label>
                        <Hyperlink Click="ConfigurePassangersList_Click">
                            <TextBlock>Accounts</TextBlock>
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </Label>
                </StackPanel>
```

Here On click of HyperLinks I am doing -

```
private void ConfigureAccounts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentGrid.Children.Clear();
        //Here is the animation
        ContentGrid.Children.Add(new ConfigureAccounts());
    }
    private void ConfigurePassangersList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentGrid.Children.Clear();
        //Here is the animation
        ContentGrid.Children.Add(new ConfigurePassangersList());
    }
```

The two constructors which I am calling are simply UserControls.

Answer (score 2):

The [WPF Bag of Tricks](http://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=wpf%20bag%20of%20tricks&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot&ei=aRY2UfmXBYK2rQGgsYB4&usg=AFQjCNGOVY3ndrESJo3rLj52RKTOPt-siw&bvm=bv.43148975,d.aWM) has a `TransitionPresenter` class, which is basically a `ContentPresenter` that supports animated transitions:

Basic usage:

```
  <bot:TransitionPresenter Content="{Binding SomeViewModelForWhichYouHaveADataTemplateDefined}">
      <bot:TransitionPresenter.Transition>
          <bot:FadeTransition Duration="00:00:00.3"/>
      </bot:TransitionPresenter.Transition>
  </bot:TransitionPresenter>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of mouse hover options ..change the colours.it would be a simple one to give a start.

And i dont call this as animation.if you really need animation for this.you need to start up with flash scripting animation.this is the better one for navigation animation.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: ok..let me know what user controls u have so that i can see if i can suggest anything better

Comment: As per my knowledge when i was working on the PHP there is a CSS concept which can be implemented here.
Style sheets can be applied so that when ever there is a hover on the hyprlink you can get the colour change kinda thing.

Try using the style sheet and check if that works

Comment: @user2075017 WTH are you talking about? this is WPF not PHP.

Comment: Also learning HTML5 animation would be much more beneficial than Flash scripting, my forward thinking opinion.

Comment: @HighCore I think you misunderstood..i never said that this is PHP.i just said when i was working in php i did it.

Anyways thanks for letting me know that this is WPF